# Datasource template

Tags: jboss, datasource, wildfly

I have dozens of datasources in the standalone.xml file of Wildfly 10, like the example below.

They all share the same details, except the connection URL and the username/password.

**Is there a way to define a "template" to avoid duplicating all the common configuration?**

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/my-db" pool-name="my-db">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/my-db</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>xxxxx</user-name>
        <password>xxxxx</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLStaleConnectionChecker"/>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
    </validation>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```